# visual studio - SQLDriverConnect is failing (returning SQL_ERROR)

Tags: c++, sql, c, visual-studio, odbc

I am trying to connect to a database I created in SQL Server Management Studio from Visual Studio 2017 in C++, but the function SQLDriverConnect is not connecting, it's failing and returning SQL_ERROR for some reason.

 this is the code I am using: (I took it from the internet, and I saw it in many other websites)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sql.h>

using namespace std;

void showSQLError(unsigned int handleType, const SQLHANDLE& handle)
{
    SQLCHAR SQLState[1024];
    SQLCHAR message[1024];
    if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLGetDiagRec(handleType, handle, 1, SQLState, NULL, message, 1024, NULL))
        cout << "SQL driver message: " << message << "\nSQL state: " << SQLState << "." << endl;
}

int main()
{
    SQLHANDLE SQLEnvHandle = NULL;
    SQLHANDLE SQLConnectionHandle = NULL;
    SQLHANDLE SQLStatementHandle = NULL;
    SQLRETURN retCode = 0;

    do {
        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &SQLEnvHandle))
            break;

        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetEnvAttr(SQLEnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))
            break;

        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLEnvHandle, &SQLConnectionHandle))
            break;

        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetConnectAttr(SQLConnectionHandle, SQL_LOGIN_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)5, 0))
            break;

        SQLCHAR retConString[1024]; 
        switch (SQLDriverConnect(SQLConnectionHandle, NULL, (SQLCHAR*)"DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=DESKTOP-MYSERVER\\SQLEXPRESS, 1433; DATABASE=mydatabase; UID=sa; PWD=mypassword;", SQL_NTS, retConString, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)) {
            
        case SQL_SUCCESS:
            std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
            break;
        case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
            std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
            break;
        case SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND:
            showSQLError(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLConnectionHandle);
            retCode = -1;
            break;
        case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
            showSQLError(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLConnectionHandle);
            retCode = -1;
            break;
        case SQL_ERROR:
            cout << "Here" << endl; // it is failing here <<<<<<
            showSQLError(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLConnectionHandle);
            retCode = -1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        if (retCode == -1)
            break;

        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, SQLConnectionHandle, &SQLStatementHandle))
            break;

        //Some sql query execution after connecting to the database.
    } while (FALSE);

    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, SQLStatementHandle);
    SQLDisconnect(SQLConnectionHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLConnectionHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQLEnvHandle);

    getchar();
}
```

I have tried all possible solutions suggested on the internet, such as running VS as administrator, putting `Trusted_Connection=yes;` instead of UID/PWD, putting `localhost` in SERVER or some suggested that I should enable TCP/IP and Named Pipes in SQL Server Configuration and SQL Server Browser in Services.

But none of those have worked, I have added my database with `sa` username to ODBC DSN User and DSN System, also no luck.
This is what I'm getting in the console:

[image]

Am I missing something? What is going on?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, what's unlear about the error message you see? Did you check that the server exists and you have access to it  using a different console program?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have tried searching for that error, in order to see solution and maybe suggestion on how to check if it exists, but nothing helped actually.
I am also able to access the database though PHP connection (for example website and php functions, that's working), but in VS it's not (C++)

Comment: So that's proof that the server exists, must have to do something with the access rights then. That's why I suggested you might try another console client to connect with that server.

Comment: Well apparently I had to enable TCP/IP in SQL server configuration AND add the port 1433 (the port field was empty in the properties there...)

Comment: If you solved it, feel free to write your own answer with the detailed steps below. Maybe it helps others visiting here.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone facing the problem, I fixed it by adding the port 1433 in SQL Server Configuration > TCP/IP > Properties > IP Addresses tab (at the end).
Also Enabling TCP/IP.